# Visual Studio Web Deploy error deploying to Linux App Service - could not complete request to remote agent

Tags: azure, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a .NET Core application which I am deploying to a Linux App Service on Azure. I use the Web Deploy option in Visual Studio 2019 (accessed through Build - Publish). This has always worked before but today it failed. I get an error validating the connection:

Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://waws-prod.....publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site='mysite'. The operation has timed out.

Naturally I have tried this several times. Looking at Microsoft's troubleshooting for Web Deploy (which is dated 2012) the closest answers seem to relate to the Remote Agent Service on the remote computer, but the troubleshooting steps relate to Windows not Linux.

Have tried restarting the app service. Also tried restarting Windows in case the issue is at the Visual Studio end - but it doesn't look like that.

Workaround currently is to use Deploy to Azure in VS Code which works.

**Update**

I have not fixed this problem but it did me a favour. It was the impetus to set up an alternative using Azure Devops Pipelines, which despite some frustration getting started has proved a much better solution. Every commit now runs all the tests on Linux, whereas before I always ran the tests on Windows. I've also set this up so that if the tests pass, it deploys automatically to a staging slot on Azure App Service. So far it has been perfectly reliable. EF migrations also work. It is easier to troubleshoot than Web Deploy which is pretty much a black box. So I recommend switching away from Web Deploy to Azure DevOps Pipelines.

Further update: the problem fixed itself, no changes on my side. However I still now prefer Pipelines!

Tim

Comment: I suggest you download publish file from portal and import to vs2019. Then deploy again to test. If not works, your solutions maybe the best.

Comment: Can you post an answer?

Comment: @JasonPan I can try this but I don't think the issue is with the publish profile. If I create a new profile in Visual Studio I get the same error. The error it seems to me is about the communication with the agent.

Comment: Okay, can you send your answer. Remember to paste the version number of the vs client and the detailed problems encountered.

Comment: This can better help other forum users to solve similar problems.

Comment: @JasonPan tried the exported publish profile and indeed same error. I don't have an answer to post other than to use a different method to publish the app.

Comment: I'm running into this issue with .Net 5 on Linux